# FirebaseUI for iOS populateCellWithBlock error

Tags: ios, swift, firebaseui

I am using CollectionView instead of TableView and I wanted to populate the CollectionViewCell through a CustomCollectionViewCell and I wander if that could work.

I am getting an error:

> Could not cast value of type `UICollectionViewCell` to
>   `CustomCollectionViewCell`

Also I am not using a xib.  What is the correct method of casting a cell to a custom collection view cell?

```
dataSource = FirebaseCollectionViewDataSource.init(query: getQuery(), modelClass: Post.self, cellReuseIdentifier: "Cell", view: self.collectionView!)

dataSource?.populateCellWithBlock() {

    let cell = $0 as! CustomCollectionViewCell

    let post = $1 as! Post

    cell.textLabel.text = post.author            
}
```

The CustomCollectionViewCell.swift is as shown below:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!

}
```

Comment: Show your `CustomCollectionViewCell` code.

Comment: @shim CustomCollectionViewCell.swift is added in the question...

Comment: Did you register the custom class? (i.e. `collectionView.registerClass(CustomCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")` in your `viewDidLoad` method)

Comment: I tried to register the class but no luck, getting the same error.  I can see in the cell it is filled with the right data from Firebase.  My understanding of this Firebasedatabaseui is that it will magically dequeue for you according to your CustomCollectionViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

Try using prototypeReuseIdentifier: "Cell" instead of cellReuseIdentifier: "Cell"